# Angular Soap: wsdl is null

Tags: angularjs, web-services, soap, wsdl

Im trying to setup a project with Angular and Soap. I found this on Github (https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap) which allows me to post a SOAP request in Angular.

But, I get an error that the wsdl is not null. Is there anybody here who can help me?

```
TypeError: wsdl is null soapclient.js:165:6
```

Code in controller:

```
var base_url = "http://www.ignyte.com/webservices/ignyte.whatsshowing.webservice/moviefunctions.asmx";

    $scope.submit = function(){
        var data = {
            month: 12,
            year: 2016
        };
        $soap.post(base_url, "GetUpcomingMovies", data).then(function(response){;
            console.log("data", response);
        })
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend not to use soapclient.js it has lot of issues

Comment: @Sajeetharan is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that’s not a wsdl file, you need

```
var base_url = 'http://www.ignyte.com/webservices/ignyte.whatsshowing.webservice/moviefunctions.asmx?WSDL';
```